# How to forecast expected volatility from high-frequency equity panel data?

Tags: volatility, time-series, equities, research, forecasting

I'm wading through the vast sea of literature on realized volatility estimation and expected volatility forecasting (see, e.g. [Realized Volatility](http://ssrn.com/abstract=1092203) by Andersen and Benzoni, which cites 120 other papers, and [Volatility](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/federico.bandi/research/br_handbook.pdf) by Bandi and Russell, which cites a slightly overlapping set of 120 papers).

I'm having a tough time finding research that specifically addresses the simultaneous estimation of a broad cross-section of equity volatility from high-frequency returns time-series.  I'm looking for something along the lines of [Vector Autoregression (VAR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression), but applying both sophisticated techniques developed for large equity panel estimation (thousands of volatilities and potentially millions of correlations being estimated) and using recent advances developed for [efficient estimation using high frequency data](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/751/how-to-forecast-volatility-using-high-frequency-data).

**What papers address the specific problem of forecasting the cross-section of equity volatility from high frequency data?**

Comment: Isn't one of the more standard approaches to estimate a variance-covariance matrix? To get past the dimensionality issue you first build a factor model and create factor based covariance matrix. Wouldn't this result in a simultaneous estimation of the cross-section of equity volatility? This is covered in Grinold and Kahn Active Portfolio Management. You could innovate in how you estimate your betas (using a dynamic linear model for example). In this case your question becomes "How do I estimate Betas via Vector Autoregression"?

Comment: @QuantGuy these covariance matrices are typically estimated from daily (or lower frequency) data.  When using higher-frequency data, handling asynchronous trading and lead-lag becomes crucial.  The problem is that most volatility estimators using HF data focus on an individual instrument.

Comment: If you have panel data then your data is not high frequency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know the short answer is negative: there isn't a well developed theory of how to *forecast* cross-sectional realized volatility. From the perspective of statistics/econometrics, most of the recent research is still trying to find its way around *estimation* of cross-sectional realized volatility, and so far even in these area the progress is slow.

Bringing modern techniques to panel data amounts to being able to:

1. extract information irregularly spaced transaction data (UHFT or tick level),
2. deal with "microstructure noise",

in a multivariate setting where the additional problems of non-synchronous trading and high-dimensionality complicates the analysis, together with the usual hassle that comes with HAC estimators (such as the dimensionality issues that @QuantGuy mentions).

There are two main tools for tackling estimation: (1) the pre/post averaging approach of Ait-Sahalia, Mykland, Renault (and others) and (2) the kernel smoothing of Barndorff-Nielsen, Hansen (and others) [the third child, i.e. VAR and its crew, seems on the sideline of late, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong here]. Of these two approaches, only the second has matured a technology (Multivariate realised kernels) that is published ([here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407611000029)).

Comment: where could i read about microstructure noise?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [A Blocking and Regularization Approach to High Dimensional Realized Covariance Estimation](http://ssrn.com/abstract=1490414).

Abstract:

> We introduce a blocking and regularization approach to estimate high-dimensional covariances using high-frequency data. Assets are first grouped according to liquidity. Using the multivariate realized kernel estimator of Barndorff-Nielsen et al. (2010), the covariance matrix is estimated block-wise and then regularized. The performance of the resulting blocking and regularization (‘RnB’) estimator is analyzed in an extensive simulation study mimicking the liquidity and market microstructure features of the S&P 1500 universe. The RnB estimator yields efficiency gains for varying liquidity settings, noise-to-signal ratios and dimensions. An empirical application of estimating daily covariances of the S&P 500 index confirms the simulation results.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it looks highly relevant, I'll check it out.  You are literally seconds too late for the bounty, though, sorry.